# Run on UI Thread Error Room Database Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on Android Application that has to show Data from Room Database Into Recycler-View . As I try to Load Data It is giving me the Error Like

```
 Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Like I have calling the Method in the Default thread.

```
   override fun getAllDatFromDatabase( appDatabase: AppDatabase) {
    var list = listOf<TodoEntity>()
    try {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            list = appDatabase.TodoDao().getAll()
            Log.d("hello","hello")
            mView.showAllData(list)
            }
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Log.d("get hello",e.toString())
    }
}
```

I am using Kotlin and

[image]

This is using `coroutineScope`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Problem Regarding to `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views` can only Be Resolved by Putting the Method that is using the thread should put under the `UIThread`

```
override fun showAllData(note_list: List<TodoEntity>) {
    activity?.runOnUiThread{
        for(note in note_list){
            titleList.add(note.qrcreatedtextdata)
            detailLogoList.add(note.texttypedata)
            for (title in titleList){
                bitmaptitle.add(CreateQRBitmap(title))
            }
        }
        Main_recyclerview!!.adapter = MainAdapter(requireContext(),titleList,detailLogoList,bitmaptitle)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not update the ui from background thread, Use `Dispatchers.Main` to switch to main thread.

```
    override fun getAllDatFromDatabase( appDatabase: AppDatabase) {
        var list = listOf<TodoEntity>()
        try {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                list = appDatabase.TodoDao().getAll()
                Log.d("hello","hello")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){ //switch to main thread
                   mView.showAllData(list)
                }
              }
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            Log.d("get hello",e.toString())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `launch` instead of `withContext`?

Comment: I have added Run on DispacherMain Altready

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  yeah you're right, withContext is better in this case because we only need to switch context rather than launching a new coroutine. Thanks